# Подстановка значений с блокировкой полей

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли через JS заблокировать выпадающий список, а подставлять значения туда в зависимости от выбранных значений в других выпадающих списках.

Пример

Есть 3 поля: 
1-е поле "Тип вмешательства" со значениями "АКШ", "Ангиография" и "Стентирование КА" - это должно быть поле заблокировано для пользователя и его значение определяется значением двух других форм

2-е поле "Вид вмешательства" - со значениями "ККГ" и "АКШ", при выборе "АКШ" - это же значение ставится в первое поле.

и 3-е поле "Стентирование" - со значениями "без значимых поражений","стентирование не выполнено" и "стентирование выполнено", где при выборе "без значимых поражений","стентирование не выполнено", первое поле меняется на "Ангиография", а при выборе "стентирование выполнено", первое поле меняется на "Стентирование КА"

Прошу прощения за термины, и в целом корявую постановку вопроса, на доработку досталась система "на костылях", и критически важно оставлять это самое первое поле, т.к. его значение передаётся в базу и по нему строится статистика, т.е. менять его нельзя.

Можно не полный пример, а просто логику, я в JS слабо разбираюсь, но если пойму логику, постараюсь сделать сам. 
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Требуется выставить аттрибут selected нужному option:

```js
$('#button').click(() => {
 $('#select option:last').attr('selected', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="select" disabled="">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
</select>
</div>


<button id="button">press</button>
```

Comment: К сожалению всё выводится через PHP - атрибут просто так не присвоить `array( name=>'type_intervention', type =>'select', label=>'Тип Вмешательства', default_array_value=>array('chkv', 'akb', 'angiodr'), default_array_label=>array("Стентирование КА, ЧКВ", "АКШ", "Ангиография")),`